# how to fetch user facebook friends names,count and id in app?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I am making an app in which if user login with facebook then he is able to share the things with his friends.so that's why i have to fetch the facebook friends in my app

Comment: you have to set permission array while you are requesting on facebook for login like  NSArray *permissionsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_about_me",@"user_relationships",@"user_birthday",@"user_location", @"offline_access", @"email",  nil]; after fetching permission you have to link your current account with facebook to share information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only be able to get the friends which also use your app, and you'll need the `user_friends` permission for that.

Please read the docs first:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_login
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

Quotes:

> - Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has its own permission: Asking for access to a person's friend list is now a separate permission that your app must request. The new permission is called user_friends.
> - Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the list of friends that have authorized your app.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                  NSDictionary* result,
                                  NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %lu friends", (unsigned long)friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.objectID);
    }
}];
```

Comment: This code is showing error on facebook sdk 3.14